# Calculate rows where date is less than year away

Tags: openoffice-calc

Im trying to write function for my logbook in OpenOffice calc.

I have rows that have a date in one of the cells. 
Im looking for solution how to calculate rows that have date less than year from today.

I got it working by adding extra cell that calculates days from today, eg.

```
=DAYS(B7;TODAY())
```

and then use that field as `COUNTIF()`reference, as

```
=COUNTIF(C7:C2177;"<365")
```

But I would really like to get rid of that extra cell, as its messing up other things in that spreadsheet.

Is there a way to use variables in cell functions, or how could I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count all dates between a year ago and a year from now:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B7:B2177>TODAY() - 365, B7:B2177<TODAY() + 365)
```

This is adapted from https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Conditional_Counting_and_Summation#Tips_and_Tricks:_Items_Between_Two_Dates.

Comment: Works like a charm, must have missed that wiki page. Cheers!